# How do I fix typeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str' in this code

Tags: python-3.x

```
v2sat=input()
v2minut=input()
print('Jelena je stigla na stanicu u:', v2sat,v2minut)
v1sat=input()
v1minut=input()
print('Ivana je stigla na stanicu u:', v1sat,v1minut)
v2sekunde=(v2sat*60*60)+(v2minut*60)
v1sekunde=(v1sat*60*60)+(v1minut*60)
razlika= (int(v1sekunde)) - (int(v2sekunde))/60/60 #The error appears here
print('Razlika je:', razlika('sati'))
```

I would really appriciate if u could help me.

Comment: Convert the inputs (strings) to numbers: `v2sat = int(input())` or `v2sat = float(input())` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your variables to integers before you start multiplying them.

```
v2sat=int (input())
v2minut=int (input())
print('Jelena je stigla na stanicu u:', v2sat,v2minut)
v1sat=int (input())
v1minut=int (input())
print('Ivana je stigla na stanicu u:', v1sat,v1minut)
v2sekunde=(v2sat*60*60)+(v2minut*60)
v1sekunde=(v1sat*60*60)+(v1minut*60)
razlika= ((v1sekunde - v2sekunde)/60/60)
print('Razlika je:', razlika)
```

Look at what this does:

```
v2sat = input ()
print (v2sat * 7)
print (int (v2sat) * 7)
```

Answer (score 0):

The inputs by default are set to strings so if you are using numbers you have to specify "MyVariable = int(input())"